# long run from main

Tags: water

I am getting city water (have a well now). The pipe from the main to the meter box is 3/4 inch. The distance from the meterbox to the house is 650 to 700 feet. Does it make any sense to run a 1 inch line from the meterbox to the house to combat friction loss? The house has mostly 1/2 inch lines of various material-copper plastic- it's a 160 year old farm house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Some more details (e.g. what's your max expected water flow) might help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: How far VERTICALLY is it?  What is the elevation difference?

Comment: the meter is about 6 to 8  feet higher than the entry into the house. the second floor of the house would be 6 to 8 feet higher than the meter and there is a 2nd story bathroom

Comment: If cost was not a huge difference you could even consider running 1.25 inch size for that long distance.

Comment: For the cost differential, I would put in 1" or even 1.25"--even if it doesn't improve the situation because one day the water co. may replace the mains in your area and you could upgrade to a larger meter. You'd hate to dig that line twice, wouldn't you? @Michael Karas is right.

Comment: I would use 1” or larger if you only use 3/4 at that distance when you open a hose bib or bath tub faucet the pressure is going to dive. I would probably make sure there is room for a pressure tank to be added where you bring it into the home and possibly a booster pump but not put those in unless needed. @ Michael karas that should be an answer+

Answer (score 1):

The intuition of the commenters is good. There are online tables if you want to to calculate it. The vertical distances that you mentioned are not significant. 8 feet of elevation is about 3.5 psi.

[image]
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pressure-loss-copper-pipes-d_930.html

Let's assume that you want a flow rate of 10 gallons per minute, and the pipe length is 700 feet. The pipe losses are as follows:

```
3/4"    91 psi loss    (700 * 0.13)  - Clearly unacceptable
1"      21 psi loss    (700 * 0.03)  - Might be OK depending on your street pressure
1 1/4"  8 psi loss     (700 * 0.011) - Good, this is where I would want to be
```