# Water line runs 600 feet from meter to gate of property?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, pvc, meter

Would there be a benefit if I have a 1" meter that is 600 feet away from property to up size the pipe from  1" to  1 1/2" pipe?

Comment: Do you have any problems?

Comment: I currently have a 1" pipe running the 600 feet but nothing on the lot no problems as of now. I am going to put a new mobile home that requires fire sprinklers so I want to make sure I have enough pressure.

Comment: Need to know the static pressure and the expected flow rate to run calculations. At 10 gal/min (reasonable for residential, not sure about sprinklers), for a 600 ft run, you will lose 18 psi with 1" pipe and 7 psi with 1.25" pipe. See my answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/175583/long-run-from-main/175640

Comment: Get a pressure reading at the end of the pipe run and determine if it is equal to or greater than what you need.  You don't want to just replace 600' of pipe if you don't need to.

Comment: ok thank I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: Simple comment:  Bigger is better. If you can afford the larger pipe, do it. No negatives for a larger pipe other than cost.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing there will be tests and requirements for the sprinklers to meet code; they'd matter more than our opinions. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I agree with @jack, at 600’ it might be cheaper to put in a holding tank and booster pump than digging and new lines. I would definitely want to know the minimum requirements before dropping that much on new pipe.